# How to call a function inside body using rest assured with Selenium

Tags: java, json, rest, selenium, rest-assured

I'm trying to call a function inside rest assured - body for post request but it doesn't work instead it is considering as a value:

And if I replace it with 123 or any no. then it works. But if every time I need to enter manually then I don't find the logic to use rest assured (even in postman I can use randomInt function to generate random numbers.)
        Please suggest is there any way to call function because for my scenario every time the number should be unique?

Here is my sample code:

```
body("{" + 
        "\"OrderReferenceNumber\": \"generateRandomNumber(3)\"," + 
        "\"Recipient\": {" + ............so on............
"}")

**generateRandomNumber(3)** is a function which generates random no. up to 3 decimal.
```

Comment: Use an editor with syntax colouring (like StackOverflow has) to be able to spot errors like this. The code, `generateRandomNumber(3)` is in the same colour as the other parts of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you current implementation you are adding name of the function to a body instead a result. One of the working example:

```
body("{" + "\"OrderReferenceNumber\": \"" + generateRandomNumber(3) + "\"," + "\"Recipient\": {" + "}}")
```